# How can I paginate a $geoNear query in MongoDB correctly and efficiently?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, graphql, graphql-js

I have a GraphQL API with a resolver to get business locations ordered by distance from MongoDB and I need pagination.

Currently my resolver definition is:

```
locationsNearby(coordinates: [Float!]! first: Int after: Float): [Location]!
```

Where `first` is the number of results to get and `after` is the minimal distance from where start to get them.

So, I have the next MongoDB query:

```
$geoNear: {
  spherical: true,
  near: { coordinates, type: "Point" },
  limit: first,
  minDistance: after,
  distanceField: "distance",
}
```

But the trouble is I can have several locations with the same distance, for example, the businesses in a same building at diferent floors.

For example with the next dataset:

```
{ id: 1, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [10, 10] }, // distance: 10
{ id: 2, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [20, 20] }, // distance: 20
{ id: 3, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [20, 20] }, // distance: 20
{ id: 4, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [20, 20] }, // distance: 20
{ id: 5, geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: [30, 30] }, // distance: 30
```

When I query `first: 2 after: 0` i get IDs `[1, 2]` all correct, but when I query `first: 2 after: 20` I get IDs `[2, 3]`.

My best aproach was sum 1meter but it don't solve the trouble, since: when I query `first: 2 after: 0` I get IDs `[1, 2]` all correct, but when I query `first: 2 after: 21` I get IDs `[5]`.

Searching I find this old blog post: https://emptysqua.re/blog/paging-geo-mongodb/

But if I understand well the post, the proposed solution is to send all previus IDs in the query. So, if I request 100 result per page and I get 11 pages, for example, to get page 11 I will need to send 1000 IDs. Don't seem very well solution.